# Brother network multifunction printers: how to modify scan target?

Tags: windows, networking, scanner

To use the scanner function of a Brother networked multifunction printer on Windows, a software named `Control Center` has to be installed (it is shipped with the drivers).
During the installation of `Control Center`, it pair the scanner and the computer. Once done, you can press a button on the scanner and the document is sent to the computer through the intermediary of `Control Center` waiting in the notification zone.

If for whatever reason the pairing is lost (I see it often), the scanner no longer find the computer.
It is still possible to scan from the computer using `Control Center`, but it is not possible to scan from the printer with the button.

The only way I found to do the pairing again is to uninstall `Control Center`, reboot, download `Control Center`, reinstall `Control Center`, reboot.
I did not found a software to do it, nor a configuration item on the printer. The official documentation say nothing about this, and a search engine give me no clue.

I suspect the pairing informations are stored on the printer because the name of the computer is displayed on the LCD even when the computer is turned off.

Question: is there a better way to pair them again?

Comment: Have you considered setting it up to scan to a network share? Would probably be more consistent and less chance of failure. Plus if you have a NAS unit, you could just scan directly to that and any computer on the network access it.

Comment: @GregoryMOUSSAT Have you tried toggling from the Brother printer to use USB and then back to wifi again to see if that works? Otherwise, I agree with the above comment to scan to the network location from the printer and have the end user check the path on the network from the machine to get the scanned document(s). You can setup a shortcut pointing to it, etc. for the users.

Comment: (1) Does the computer have two connections to the same router, meaning wired and wireless or two wireless connections? (2) Are you using the latest Brother driver? (3) Try the procedure in points 5 & 6 in this [troubleshooting guide](https://windowsreport.com/brother-printer-scan-issues/).

Comment: Could you post..:?
1) The exact error message you see. An image would be even better.
2) The model of your scanner.
3) The OS in your PC
4) The brand/model of your PC
5) The driver you have (TWAIN or WIA)
6) How are you connecting the scanner and PC

Comment: A few links (may or may not be useful)
1. https://support.brother.ca/app/answers/detail/a_id/83912/~/how-to-download-and-install-the-control-center4-update
2. https://download.brother.com/welcome/doc002846/cv_mfc825dw_chne_soft.pdf
3. https://help.brother-usa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/74876/~/check-cable%2C-check-connection%2C-or-connecting-to-pc-when-scanning--
4. https://help.brother-usa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/164734/~/configure-the-scan-to-pc-button-using-brother-iprint%26scan---windows-or

Comment: 5. https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81c5uDGGZHS.pdf
6. https://help.brother-usa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/137646/~/scan-a-document-into-paperport---twain-or-wia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the pairing is lost:

1. run `Brother Utilities` from the start menu
2. clic on `Scanners and Cameras` (same as running `C:\Program Files\Windows Photo Viewer\ImagingDevices.exe`)
3. select the desired scanner and use the different tabs to reconfigure the pairing (choose betwen ip address or computer name, and display name for the LCD screen)

I wonder how I did not found it earlier because it is not so embeeded in the depths of someting hard to find.

Comment: I also wonder how people dare to post comments as what can be seen below the question, without knowing anything on the subject. Even some are directing to a complete different way to do things (you want to switch your heating system from electricity to gas? Nah, did you considered to move to another country instead?).